# I want to load different layouts with fragments in recyclerview. is that possible?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to a load different layouts with fragments in recyclerview. is that possible? if possible is that a good practice to use different layout fragments in recyclerview. I have idea of like using different card layouts in Recyclerview by overriding the getItemViewType() method from RecyclerView Adapter. Could anyone provide a sample for loading different layouts using fragments as row items in RecyclerView android

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I want to load different layouts with fragments in recyclerview. is that possible?

of course it is possible, but a bad practice. Instead try to use child layouts.

> I have idea of like using different card layouts in Recyclerview by overriding the getItemViewType()

ya, this is the right place to get started. cheers (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a item layout for your recyclerview with a FrameLayout as fragment container.

You will need a reference to your fragment manager in your adapter , set with a function or put into the adapter constructor.

In the onBindViewHolder function of your adapter you manage which fragment should be created in function of the position.

This is a suggestion at your issue but it is against good practice.

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english .